# Is it a bad idea to make a command with the same name as an environment?

Tags: environments, programming

So I have defined an environment `{sseqpage}` where the body of the environment consists of options to control the appearance of an image. If no body is present, then the image can still be displayed just fine. Thus, I have defined a command that is shorthand for a copy of my environment with empty body `\begin{sseqpage}[#1]\end{sseqpage}`.

I am now tempted to define the command to check whether it is being used as an environment as follows:

```
\def\sseqpage{%
    \def\sseq@temp{sseqpage}%
    \ifx\@currenvir\sseq@temp
        \@xp\sseqpage@environmentcase % we're being used as an environment
    \else
        \@xp\sseqpage@commandcase
    \fi
}
```

Note for instance that `tikz` could use shenanigans like this to make `\tikz` and `\begin{tikz} ... \end{tikz}` work, rather than calling the environment form `{tikzpicture}`.

What are the drawbacks of doing this?

Comment: Such tricks are done by `beamer`; avoid it.

Comment: I wouldn't do it because it might get confusing to use and maintain at some point. Are you the only one who will use that?

Comment: No, this is for a package. There is a concern that other people could suffer for my poor decision making.

Comment: By the way, `\tikz...;` does `\begin{tikzpicture}...;\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: technically it would probably work, but I think it would be confusing  to humans

Comment: Note that if you use the trick if you nest it such as `\begin{x} ... \x ... \end{x}` then the inner `\x` will not be able to detect. One possible elaborate workaround is to use a begin-environment hook to set some flag, then check for the flag value when the command is called // also I think \begin{tikz}...\end{tikz} just "happen to work" by the default behavior of how LaTeX environment is implemented, it's not an intended feature of TikZ.

Comment: Remark: `beamer` class let `\frame` works as both a command and an environment, but as stated in the documentation it's just for supporting legacy documents, thus not really encouraged. Nevertheless, the way `beamer` does it, make `\frame{...}` mistakenly think that it's an environment when used nested in another `frame` environment -- but `\frame` is not supposed to be nested anyway (as inside a `frame` environment, `\frame` has the meaning equal to `\framelatex{...}` i.e. put a box around the text inside `...`) so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 10):

While it's technically possible, this breaks the documented latex syntax (or is the documented syntax, depending on details that are not clear).

LaTeX documents that any command may be used as an environment so

```
\begin{small}...\end{small}
```

acts like

```
{\small ...}
```

even though there is no specific `small` environment defined.

Similarly if you have defined a command

```
\newcommand\sseqpage[1][foo]{....}
```

then that already supports any of the following

```
 \sseqpage
 \sseqpage[zzz]
 \begin{sseqpage}...\end{sseqpage}
 \begin{sseqpage}[zzz]...\end{sseqpage}
```

Your definition sketch makes `\sseqpage` act differently if it is in the scope of a `sseqpage` environment which in itself is not necessarily a bad thing (`enumerate` acts differently if it is in the scope of `enumerate` for example), but your coding hints that the syntax of the two `\...case` commands may be different which would make the syntax of `\ssseqpage` context dependent which is likely to be confusing and doesn't really follow latex syntax style.

Comment: For the record, my plan was to make the nonenvironment version to behave the same as an empty environment, so that `\sseqpage[options]` is the same as `\begin{sseqpage}[options]\end{sseqpage}`. I didn't do this because of the your advice not to.

Comment: What about `adjustbox`? Works like a charm in both fashions, and is not confusing in the least way. Or doesn't it, @MartinScharrer?

Comment: @VincentKrebs  Martin will not get an `@` ping from here. Well yes adjustbox (like \tikz, or beamer \frame) has a mandatory extra `{...}` argument to detect the command form which makes it possible although I'd not necessarily recommend it.